# Is there a way to see all the available variables inside content?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I am using Drupal 9 with twig files

I have a page where in one section I need to show thumbnails of the latest posts. So I created a new view as a block, and placed this block under Content in admin/structure/block/list/

When I inspect with debug on I get these file suggestions -

```
 FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--views-block--latest-news-block-1.html.twig
   * block--views-block--latest-news-block-1.html.twig
   * block--views-block.html.twig
   * block--views.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
```

So I created a file name block--views-block--latest-news-block-1.html.twig with the code from block.html.twig.

Inside that file I have -

```
    {% block content %}
      {{ content }}
    {% endblock %}
```

Which shows all the content in the block. I need to customize the content in the block though, some things need to be removed, I need to truncate the article text, need to add buttons.

I think I'd be able to do what I want if I could target specific parts of the content. I want to do something like this -

```
<div class="card">
     <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
     <p>{{ content.body }}</p>
</div>

Is there a way to target specific parts of the content like that?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it works that way but Views templates may be different.

1. [Enable Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates#s-enable-debugging).
2. Add Devel and Kint: `composer require drupal/devel kint-php/kint`
3. Enable Devel: `drush -y en devel`
4. Inside the template put `{{ kint(content) }}`, flush caches, visit the page and you should see what else can be found inside `content`.